# Validating for a data type in Python

Tags: python, validation

I wanted to validate the data type as int or float in this simple code, I've gone wrong somewhere and the error message "Enter an integer!" shows up no matter what. I have already tried putting a == instead of != and putting all other statements after the if, but the problem persists.

```
def menuLoop():

    marks = input("Please Enter the Obtained Marks: ")
    if type(marks) != int or float:
        print("Enter an integer!")
        menuLoop()

    else:
        if int(marks) >= 75:
            print("A")
            menuLoop()
        elif marks >= 60:
            print("B")
            menuLoop()
        elif marks >= 35:
            print("C")
            menuLoop()
        elif marks < 35:
            print("D")
            menuLoop()



menuLoop()
```

Comment: Also, note that the function recursively calling itself until it gets a valid answer can lead to all sorts of problems. Use a loop instead.

Comment: You could have simply figured out what the problem is by using python interpreter, just execute `type(mark)`. And you would be able to find out what was the problem. Try some debugging first before posting question here.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the problem is that the `input()`, by default, is neither `int` nor `float`, that is a `string`.

If you want to check if the input is in the *form* of `int`, you can do that like this:

```
try:
    # mark is going to convert in int, if it can.
    # otherwise, it will throw a ValueError
    mark = int(mark)
except ValueError:
    # Handle the exception
    print 'Please enter an integer'
    menuLoop()
```

The function `int()` raises a `ValueError`, if the given parameter is not convertible in `int`. So, after catching that `ValueError`, we can show a message that to enter an `int`eger value, like I've shown above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky, but it will fix the logic, change your condition to:

```
if not marks.replace('.','',1).isdigit():
    print("Enter an integer!")
    menuLoop()
```

It will go inside the `if` if user inputs `int` or `float`.

`.replace('.','',1)` will replace only one `.` then check that all of the other characters are number or not.